# What is the path for an image in iphone development

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have this snippet of objective c code:

```
UIImage *image = [ [UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileName];
```

fileName is set to "file1.jpg"

When I run the code, however, image is set to nil.

I know the file does exist I am guessing it has something to do with the path.

What path should I be using?

Answer (score 14):

The easiest thing to use is `imageNamed:` like this:

```
UIImage* theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"file1.jpg"];
```

If you need to use `initWithContentsOfFile:` for some reason, you need to get the path from the bundle, like this:

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file1" ofType:@"jpg"];
UIImage* theImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Comment: Also, note that imageNamed will cache image in memory for later, while initWithContentsOfFile won't - use latter if it's one shot thing and memory is important.

Comment: initWithContentsOfFile will, the only one that won't is initWithData.

Comment: The image file may not be in the bundle's root directory. If that's the case, use [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file1" ofType:@"jpg" inDirectory:@"directory/or_subdirectory"] as the path.

Answer (score 0):

To get the same behavior as your code so that your image is not autoreleased

```
UIImage* image = [[UIImage imageNamed:fileName] retain];
```

Comment: I can't see any reason to put a retain there. In your simple example you are assigning the return value to a variable in the local scope, so retaining it is almost always an error. It's better to place the retain calls where they are needed (like when assigning to a variable in the global scope or copying the variable to a pointer passed to the method, etc.)

Comment: The OP has a retain counter of +1, as such so should the response code.

Comment: The OP is clearly new to Objective-C and the Foundation framework. He/she may or may not be releasing that method call later, but there is almost never any reason for the line in your example, and IMHO, it's better not to present examples that lead to bad habits.

Answer (score 0):

And, of course, the image has to be in the bundle -- if you drag it into your project in XCode and choose copy the resource from the options, it should just find it OK.